# how to show quantitative results in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins test results screen shows only pass/failed results.
I would like to show quantitive (number/percentage/time duration etc') results, parsed from logs. 
e.g. memory usage, run time of specific methods etc..

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

good question.

i imagine you're probably looking to extend your Jenkins instance with some plugins that describe more info about the tests you've run. this plugin seems relevant, but requires some experience with JMeter (java-based performance measurment tool) to generate the *output* that this plugin can then read and display output from a JMeter task that you can run every time your build runs:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin

the 'readme' in the above plugin details page specifies how to set up a project to run JMeter( see the 'Configuring a project to run jmeter performance test:' near the bottom.

another way to do similar not so immediately tied to a specific jenkins build is to run resource monitors (like Cacti or collectd) on the machines running the tests and analyze those results post-build, but again, outside of the Jenkins context.

HTH.

Comment: to my understanding JMeter is intended for server stress testing, and not so much for logs parsing and info extraction. am i wrong?